# Roots of polynomials of $R[x]$ in the surreals

Tags: real-numbers, number-systems, surreal-numbers

I have this question and I don't know where to even begin.

The question is: Let $S$ denote the surreals. Prove or disprove: no polynomial in $R[x]$ has a root in $S \setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Help!

Comment: What is surreals?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number, it explains better than I ever could. But the short version, a totally ordered field containing the reals as a strict subset, preserving the usual four operations.

Comment: What is $R $ in your question? The same as $\mathbb R $?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** All roots of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are (standard) complex numbers.

Comment: So let's say $p(x)$ is monic and $p(x) = (x-z_1)\dots (x-z_k)$. Does it then follow that any such $y\in S\backslash \mathbb{R}$ cannot be a root because all the factors $(y-z_i)$ are non-zero? I think I'm having difficulty understanding the multiplication of elements...

Comment: I'll admit that I'm no expert in the surreal (or hyperreal) numbers, but my thought is this: if $p(x) = (x-z_1) \cdots (x-z_k)$ and all the coefficients of $p$ are real, then each $z_j$ is a complex number, so takes the form $a_j+b_ji$ for some $a_j,b_j \in \mathbb{R}$. If $b_j \ne 0$ then $z_j \not \in S$, and if $b_j=0$ then we have $z_j=a_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hmm I see. I think I got confused imagining the polynomial over the surreals. In particular, I wasn't sure if there was a factorisation of $p$ over the surreals. I'm still not sure, come to think of it...

Comment: @Cams, on "imagining the polynomial over the surreals", you *don't have* a weird polynomial over the surreals, since $\mathbb R [x] $ means "the set of polynomials with real coefficients". You're just considering substituting surreal values for $x$. On "the multiplication of elements", I don't know where this problem comes from, but you should know before this question that all properties of fields like "a product is zero only if one factor is zero" are true of the surreals. (Incidentally, pretty much anything aside from completeness that's true of the reals holds for the surreals too.)